# How to re index data without deleting in Solr

Tags: solr

Is there a way to reindex all docs in solr core?

I have made change to index time analyzer to a field in managed-schema

I have around 600 000 docs in my solr core and i don't have this data anywhere else.

How should i reindex the data?

Comment: Are all your fields set to stored? In general - you'll have to fetch all the documents from Solr and then send them back to Solr to be indexed again. To do that the original text will have to be retrievable, either by being set to stored or having docValues enabled that allows the original value to be reconstructed.

Comment: Its set to stored, but how do I do it for 6 lakhs of docs at one shot, is there a way

Comment: Write a small script that uses the `/export` endpoint to retrieve the documents, or depending on how you're indexing today, there's a hidden feature deep down in Solr which may not be supported any longer, where you could configure DIH to retrieve the original documents from a different Solr core.

Comment: Please don't use Indian measurements here. That's just going to confuse people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not wish to use the export and then reindex approach, you can use the following approach,

1. Go to the solr directory and create a new collection (newCollection) with the exact same configuration. This can be achieved using rsync.

   ```
   rsync -avz --exclude data oldCollection/ newCollection
   ```

   Make sure to exclude the data folder while running rsync. (Suggest you to do a dry run as well before actually running rsync)
2. Edit the collection name in core.properties file to newCollection.
3. Restart solr. You should start to see the newCollection in UI.
4. Now you can copy your data from oldCollection to newCollection using a simple script which fetches data from oldCollection in batches and sends the same object to the newCollection. (You may need to handle the *version* field received from oldCollection)
5. Now you can simply swap the collections using the [Swap api](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#SWAP) to achieve this. There is a Swap button on admin UI as well for this :)

Although IMHO, I would agree with @The Bndr here. You should use Solr as a index only. Do store your data somewhere in file/database.

As mentioned in this [apache solr wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToReindex),

> Using Solr as a Data Source:
>   Don't do this unless you have no other option. Solr is not really designed for this role. Every attempt is made to ensure that Solr is stable, but indexes do get corrupted by unanticipated situations, and by things completely outside developer control. Solr 4.x and later does have NoSQL features, and SolrCloud goes a long way towards high availability, but absolute data reliability in the face of any problem is difficult to achieve for any software, which is why it's always important to have backups.

Answer (score 2):

Solr is an fulltext-index, not an database. So it's best practices to hold your data somwhere else outside solr, like in files or an database.

So your only solution is to export your data from solr, like it is recommended in the comment from @MatsLindh
Google will help you, to find a way (or a tool) to dump/export your stored data to JSON or XML (or whatever)

Once you have stored your documents outside solr, reindexing after changing the schema will be easy in the future.